# Are my statistically significant results invalid if I fail to reach my desired sample size?

Tags: sample-size, statistical-power

I conducted an unfunded study where 3 groups of 15 participants were observed over 11 timepoints. There were statistically significant between-group differences in slope and also statistically significant differences between-groups at certain time points (adjusted for multiple comparisons).

I aimed to get 20 participants per group, and, I am ashamed to confess, performed no power calculations ahead of time, as my estimates of how many I would need per group were based on studies in my field that had observed significant effects (and also on very realistic issues around recruitment).

So please forgive those sins. My question is:

**If a study fails to reach its desired sample size and observes significant effects, are those effects invalidated by that failure?** (or do those significant effects still stand?)

Comment: The main purpose of advance power calculations is to use a large enough sample that you will have a good chance of rejecting the null hypothesis, if it is true. (Specifically, if the true mean differs from the hypothetical mean by an amount that is of practical importance.) If you got a significant result with a smaller sample size than a power analysis would have recommended, that does not invalidate the significant result. (Either you were lucky or have good intuition on sample sizes.) The only remaining question is whether the observed difference is also of practical importance.

Comment: Thank @BruceET, most reassuring. The same reviewer that asked for the power calculations also asked about clinical significance. How does one demonstrate practical importance with scores on a questionnaire (i.e. when the outcome is *not* risk of an event or time to heal or something concrete)? Effect sizes?

Comment: That's really a med question rather than a stat one. Certainly, I couldn't say based on what little context I know. // Maybe overall scores on questionnaires were 100 pts. Then a difference of 1 or 2 pts between two groups might not be of much interest. But a difference of 10 or 15 might. // If questionnaires are about quality of life or amount of pain, you might make a case by giving a profile of answers to key questions for someone who scored 85 vs someone who scored 100. (However, I might be hesitant to claim paradigm-shattering effects based on a study with 45 subjects, 15 in each group.)